# How I can access events in meeting rooms via MS Graph API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, office365api

I'd like to access all meeting rooms in a company WITHOUT delegating room calendars to user(or users). Currently I can get list of rooms but I can't get info about meetings inside any of meeting room. I can however access meetings only if calendar is delegated to me. I know I have to change Calendar Processing to see event subject instead of event organizer.

Is this even possible? I'd like to authorize admin user by single button and then have azure application to have access to all events in every meeting room so that I can see events with start/end time, subject and organizer without need to delegate room calendars to anybody.

I've read about admin consent api but I can't authorize it somehow.

Thank you :)

Comment: I've tried something like this in the past and I'm afraid it's not possible only the meeting organizer can get that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Client credentials flow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow and grant Application permissions for Calendars.Read . That by default would give you access to all Calendars in the Tenant but you can then scope it down to just the Meeting Room Mailboxes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access